# Tomcat 7.0 : Integrate with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I integrated Tomcat with Eclipse (according to proper steps). But when I try to run a project, it generates a 404 error.

Without Eclipse, when I run the project manually, the project runs successfully. The steps are given [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html).

[image: in this the project tree and DD]

[image: Run the project on server]

[image: but it will generate the 404]

[image: even i type only localhost:8080 but the server is running on eclipse , it will again generate the error]

without eclipse this code will run successfully.

Comment: which version of eclipse are you using , as the tutorial you mentioned  has the last version of tomcat as 6.0 wherein your question says you are using 7.0

Comment: yes i know , but steps are same , and there are many tutorial in google , all are follow the same steps . but when i try to run the project 404 not fount error , or even when i type only http://localhost:8080 on browser , the 404 not fount error , but the server is running in eclipse.

Comment: have you tried deploying/running via eclipse e.g. left click on project and then select run or deploy

Comment: yes , right click on project , Run on server , then add the project in server and finish . then browser open and 404 not found error , when i type only localhost:8080 , it will generate 404 but the server is start in eclipse.

Comment: try doing it this way : project , Deploy

Comment: where is deploy option ?

Comment: mea culpa , but wait a sec , could you please post a screenshot

Comment: ok . i post the project coding and screenshots.

Comment: where have you posted it

Comment: can you stop running sts and then run eclipse , just a guess

Comment: same problem... even sts close

Comment: ok , do this , stop eclipse , and then on your command prompt try the command netstat -na to see if port 8080 is still open, if yes, you may probably will have to stop the service that is using it, before starting tomcat in eclipse

Comment: in command prompt this will show " TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         127.0.0.1:51238        TIME_WAIT" i dont know what is the meaning of this .

Comment: wait for a minute and then fire the same command , if 8080 doesn't shows there , that will tell us that tomcat when run in eclipse is using this port

Comment: again i run the command , but this is this is not available . so know what i do ?

Comment: can you paste your welcome-file tag here

Comment: ok `<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>jsp/login.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list> `

Comment: post your code in github, would like to see in my eclipse

Comment: oh . you can publish your code at https://www.github.com in a code repository from where someone can pull your code to have a look at it

Comment: if you not have a problem , with the help of team viewer you want to check my code, and i also do some changes in my code, i want to show you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23885/discussion-between-satya-and-harmeet-singh)

Comment: This comment thread is getting rather lengthy. Please use chat for extended discussions.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the solution is :

copy your `jsp folder in WEB-INF directory` and then run the project on server , you will be through